# Removing Folder and random 3 characters htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url structure similare to

```
http://www.domain.com/sessionID/ABC/product-name
```

I use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sessionID/ to capture the sessionID but the subsequent folder is a random 3 character code. I want to stripe all of this so my rewrite is

```
http://www.domain.com/product-name
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is `sessionID` literally or some arbitrary id?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the product-name with a RewriteRule alone

```
RewriteRule ^.+?/.../(.+)$ /$1
```

If `sessionID` is literally in your URL, you can also use

```
RewriteRule ^sessionID/.../(.+)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but that didn't work, after some trail and error the following did the trick but tbh I am not entirely sure if it the correct use but it worked.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sessionID/.../\&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/%1%2 [R=301,L]
```